# Generator object using recursion

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, generator, bioinformatics

Python 2.7

Given a list of `alleles` and length of array `numb_alleles`, for example:

```
alleles = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
numb_alleles = 8
```

I have been trying to go through each Cartesian product and select the alleles relevant for my study which meet the following selection criteria:

1. **Every second value in the Cartesian product must be larger than the value before it.** For example, given the conditions above, the Cartesian Product `[13, 15, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 16]` would meet the selection criteria, whereas `[13, 15, 16, 12, 14, 15, 16, 16]` would not because of index 2 and 3.
2. **Every value in `alleles` must be present in the Cartesian product.**
   For example, `[13, 15, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 16]` would meet the selection criteria, whereas `[13, 15, 11, 12, 14, 15, 11, 13]` would not because `16` is not in the product.

I had been using `itertools.product(alleles, repeat = numb_alleles)` to iterate through each possible Cartesian product to analyze further. However, as `numb_alleles` increases to 10 or 12, overall computation increases significantly.

I attempted to solve this by trying to select the relevant Cartesian products using the recursive function below.

```
def check_allele(allele_combination, alleles):
    """Check if all the alleles are present in allele_combination"""
    for allele in alleles:
        if allele not in allele_combination:
            return False
    return True

def recursive_product(alleles, numb_alleles, result):
    current_len = len(result[0])
    new_result = []
    final_result = []

    for comb in result:
        for allele in alleles:
            if current_len % 2 == 0:
                new_result.append(comb + [allele])
            elif current_len % 2 == 1:
                if comb[-1] <= allele:
                    new_result.append(comb + [allele])
                    if (check_allele(comb + [allele], alleles)):
                        final_result.append(comb + [allele])

    if current_len + 1 < numb_alleles:
        return recursive_product(alleles, numb_alleles, new_result)
    else:
        return final_result

a = (recursive_product(alleles, numb_alleles, [[]]))
```

However, using this approach I am still unable to process arrays up to `numb_alleles = 12` or when the length of `alleles` increases, as I am using `return` rather than `yield`. Because of this it results in an out of memory error.

I was wondering if it is possible for me to make this function into a generator, or if anyone may suggest a different approach, so that I can further compute the outputs where `numb_alleles = 12` and longer `alleles` arrays.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please check what you wrote for your first criteria.  It doesn't make sense to me.  Indices 3 and 4 are 12 and 14 for both arrays.  Also, what does "Every second value in the Cartesian product must be smaller than the value before it." mean exactly?  15 is not smaller than 13 in the example you gave.

Comment: Thanks James for pointing out my mistake. Edited the original post. I meant "Every second value in the Cartesian product must be larger than the value before it" and index 2 and 3.

Comment: This is a good problem to solve by induction. Figure out how you get the next array from a given starting array. Then figure out your base case. Then just express the same ideas in code.

Comment: You might be able to `yield from` when you recur instead of returning. And instead of appending to `final_result` you would yield the value.

Comment: Is `numb_alleles` always even? Is `alleles` always a list of consecutive integers? It's not too hard to turn your `recursive_product` into a product, but as you've noted it's not very efficient since it has to reject a lot of the combinations it makes. I have a few ideas to improve it, but I need to test them. We can make `check_allele` a bit more efficient, but we really need a better main algorithm.

Comment: You said: "Every second value in the Cartesian product must be larger than the value before it." But in `t = [13, 15, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 16]`, `t[7] == 16`, which is _not_ larger than `t[6] == 16`. Does that mean that items at odd indices can be equal to the item at the previous even index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said: "Every second value in the Cartesian product must be larger than the value before it." But in your example `[13, 15, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 16]` the item in slot, 7 (16) is equal to the item in the previous slot, so I assume you mean that items at odd indices must be >= to the item at the previous even index.

The generator below is a little more efficient than your current approach, and it avoids holding large temporary lists in RAM. The core idea is to use `itertools.product` to generate combinations for the even slots, and then use `product` again to fill the odd slots that satisfy selection criterion #1. We use set operations to ensure that the final combination contains every item in `alleles`.

```
from itertools import product

def combine_alleles(alleles, numb_alleles):
    ''' Make combinations that conform to the selection criteria. First create
        the items for the even slots, then create items for the odd slots such
        that each odd slot item >= the corresponding even slot item. Then test
        that the whole combination contains each item in alleles.
    '''
    # If the number of unique items in the even slots is < min_len, then it's
    # impossible to make a full combination containing all of the alleles.
    min_len = len(alleles) - numb_alleles // 2

    # Create a function to test if a given combination
    # contains all of the alleles.
    alleles_set = set(alleles)
    complete = alleles_set.issubset

    # Make lists of alleles that are >= the current allele number
    higher = {k: [u for u in alleles if u >= k] for k in alleles}

    # Make combinations for the even slots
    for evens in product(alleles, repeat=numb_alleles // 2):
        if len(set(evens)) < min_len:
            continue
        # Make combinations for the odd slots that go with this
        # combination of evens.
        a = [higher[u] for u in evens]
        for odds in product(*a):
            if complete(evens + odds):
                yield [u for pair in zip(evens, odds) for u in pair]

# test

alleles = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
numb_alleles = 8

for i, t in enumerate(combine_alleles(alleles, numb_alleles), 1):
    print(i, t)
```

This code finds 16020 combinations, so the output is too large to include here.

---

Here's an alternative generator that's closer to your version, but in my tests it's a little slower than my first version.

```
def combine_alleles(alleles, numb_alleles):
    total_len = len(alleles)

    # Make lists of alleles that are >= the current allele number
    higher = {k: [u for u in alleles if u >= k] for k in alleles}

    def combos(i, base):
        remaining = numb_alleles - i
        if len(set(base)) + remaining < total_len:
            return

        if remaining == 0:
            yield base
            return

        ii = i + 1
        for u in higher[base[-1]] if i % 2 else alleles:
           yield from combos(ii, base + [u])

    yield from combos(0, [])
```

This version is for Python 3. Python 2 doesn't have `yield from`, but that's easy to fix:

```
yield from some_iterable
```

is equivalent to

```
for t in some_iterable:
    yield t
```

Comment: Very impressive (+1).

Comment: Thank you so much. I have never thought of dividing and conquering the problem like the way you have done. This is brilliant. Especially the use of the `higher` dictionary is an elegant way of tracking alleles that are higher than one another. Thanks again.